# React: how to present different UI for user with different access?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, authentication, reactjs

Using react, What is the best way to present UI with minor difference for logged in and anonymous user? E.g. For logged in user there might be comment box, logged out button, etc. for anonymous there might be sign up form, sign up button etc.

Is it better to just hide and show component based on logged in state, or design separate pages for both type of users?

Answer (score 0):

React makes this type of situation super easy to handle you can either design different components for active user and unregister user or have single components that have their own internal logic of displaying either a logout or a login/register button . Personally I'd go the route of making components for each state a user can be in either logged in or out as far the interactions you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount of differences between logged in and anonymous state and size of pages. I would go with hiding and showing components, maybe would even put `isAuthenticated` bool to context if the app is quite large to make thinks a bit easier